# Mouse pointer offset between on-screen and Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I googled this and cannot find any answer:
My emulator in Android Studio does not take the click inputs at the same position as my mouse pointer actually is. It's like the emulated touch resolution is smaller than the screen resolution: the further down or right I want to click something in Android, the more left and down relative to that position my mouse pointer has to aim - that also means I cannot click anything at the bottom of the screen. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: I see a very similar problem when I run the emulator in a tool window (Android Studio 4.1) in landscape orientation. Mapping of the mouse clicks seem to be upside-down, i.e. clicking on the lower right corner opens my app's menu on the upper right. I believe this is related to the emulator's rotate buttons, which do seem to work properly either. I have tried to find a sequence of orientation changes that keeps screen and mouse orientation in sync but have not had any luck yet.

I think it's simply a bug.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue with the tool window emulator, this USED to work I am certain of that. I do not recalling updating AS, but alas, it must have in the last couple weeks.

Answer (score 1):

It was apparently a bug in the emulator. Please update the emulator to version 30.5.3 or later and try again. In that version, the mouse offset issues I observed were resolved.

Comment: I have version 30.5.4 installed and this behaviour is still there, I have to click up and to the right to click on anything, the tool window emulator is unusable because of this issue.

Comment: @AutoM8R Sorry to hear that. Obviously, I can only comment on the particular issue I have been observing, and there might be others. But also your case looks very much like a bug. I recommend filing a bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the emulator. I got it after an emulator update. A cold boot of the emulator solved the problem.